# How to mirror files with given pattern (wildcard)

Tags: powershell, mirror, copy-item

I've got a folder with a lots of installation files inside. I would like to take some of these (found by given pattern) and mirror them to the flash drive.

**Source:**

```
D:\ccleaner124.exe
D:\dfc221.exe
D:\abc.exe
```

**Destination:**

```
H:\ccleaner123.exe
H:\dfc221.exe
```

**Pattern:** (stored directly in the script or at some .txt file)

```
D:\ccleaner*.exe
D:\dfc*.exe
```

**Result:**

*Source:* unchanged

*Destination:*

```
H:\ccleaner124.exe // deleted 123 as it had lower version number in pattern [a-zA-Z_-]*([0-9]*) and copied 124 instead
H:\dfc221.exe // current, so kept the same as it was (no copy)
```

I looked up the Copy-Item function properties, but I haven't found anything like "mirror" parameter there. Is it even possible to do this with Power Shell?

Comment: Copy-Item is not a robocopy replacement. You'll have to write custom checks/filters.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow working script (I wrote it something simmliar sometime ago). Put it in copy.ps1, modify sourceDir, destDir, and pattern array

```
function removeName($txt)
{
    $inputPattern = "^[a-z]+"
    $txt = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($txt, $inputPattern, "");
    $inputPattern = "[.][a-z]+"
    $txt = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($txt, $inputPattern, "");
    return [int]$txt;
}

$pattern = @('a*.txt', 'b*.txt')
$sourceDir = 'C:\source'
$destDir = 'C:\dest'

$pattern | foreach{
    $p = $_;
    $s = Get-ChildItem -Filter $p -Path $sourceDir;
    $sName = removeName $s.Name
    $d = Get-ChildItem -Filter $p -Path $destDir;
    $dName = removeName $d.Name
    if($sName -gt $dName)
    {
        Write-Host $s.Name 
        Write-Host $sName
        rm -Force $d.FullName
        Copy-item $s.FullName $destDir
    }
}
```